# Fourier transform of a Sobolev function dependent on a "parameter"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, let $V\in W^{1,1}_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^+)$, such that
$$ V(x,0)=u(x),\quad V(x,\cdot)\in C^0([0,\infty)),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
and suppose that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^+}y^a|\nabla_XV|^2\,dX<\infty,\quad X=(x,y).\tag{1} $$
From (1) I have that, for all $j=1,...,n$,  $\partial_jV(\cdot,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for a.e. $y>0$, and $\partial_yV(\cdot,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, for a .e. $y>0$, so there are well-defined
$ \mathcal{F}(\partial_yV(\cdot,y)), \mathcal{F}(\partial_jV(\cdot,y))\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
I want to prove the following two equalities:
$$ \mathcal{F}(\partial_jV(\cdot,y))=i\xi_j\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y)),\quad\forall j=1,...,n,\tag{2}$$
$$\partial_y\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y))=\mathcal{F}(\partial_yV(\cdot,y)).\tag{3}$$
How can I interpret $\mathcal{F}(V(\cdot,y))$ with this set of hypotheses? How I can prove (1) and (2)? I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.